# C MPI parallel programing - segmentation fault 11 error

Tags: c, parallel-processing, segmentation-fault, mpi

I have an assignment that asks me to use parallel MPI to shear sort volumes of 16 cuboids that are given from a specific file, each cuboid with a different process.
I tried to use the following code (this is not the complete code, there are some irrelevant functions that I removed). I compiled this code with no errors, but when I tried to run it I got a failure message that i suspect to have relation with my data structure and maybe a segmentation fault (my best guess is that i have malloc/pointer problems), yet anything I do can't help to solve it. Any help will be regarded.

The code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include "mpi.h"

#define LENGTH 16
#define MASTER 0

struct cube {
    int id;
    double height, length, width, volume;
}typedef cube;

void readFromFile(cube **c, char *FilePath);
void createNewCubeMPIType(MPI_Datatype *type);
MPI_Comm createCommunicator(int rank, int size, int *coardinates);
void shearSort(cube *SpecificCube, int rank, MPI_Comm Cube_Comm, int p,
        MPI_Datatype MPI_CUBE, int *coordinates);

void readFromFile(cube **c, char *FilePath) {
    FILE *fp;
    int temp;
    int counter = 0;
    fp = fopen("cuboids.dat", "r");
    if (fp == NULL) {
        printf("Error opening file\n");
        fclose(fp);
        exit(1);
    }
    do {
        temp = fscanf(fp, "%d %lf %lf %lf \n", &c[counter]->id,
                &c[counter]->length, &c[counter]->width, &c[counter]->height);
        if (temp != EOF) {
            c[counter]->volume = c[counter]->height * c[counter]->length
                    * c[counter]->width;
            counter++;
        }
    } while (temp != EOF);
    fclose(fp);
}
void createNewCubeMPIType(MPI_Datatype *type) {
    cube c;
    int blocklen[5] = { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 };
    MPI_Aint displacement[5];
    MPI_Datatype data[5] = { MPI_INT, MPI_DOUBLE, MPI_DOUBLE,
    MPI_DOUBLE, MPI_DOUBLE };
    displacement[0] = (int*) &c.id - (int*) (&c);
    displacement[1] = (int*) &c.height - (int*) &c;
    displacement[2] = (int*) &c.length - (int*) &c;
    displacement[3] = (int*) &c.width - (int*) &c;
    displacement[4] = (int*) &c.volume - (int*) &c;

    MPI_Type_create_struct(5, blocklen, displacement, data, type);
    MPI_Type_commit(type);
}

MPI_Comm createCommunicator(int rank, int size, int *coardinates) {
    MPI_Comm communicator;
    int nDimension = 2, DimentionSize = (int) sqrt(size);
    int dimensions[2] = { DimentionSize, DimentionSize };
    int period[2] = { 0, 0 };
    MPI_Cart_create(MPI_COMM_WORLD, nDimension, dimensions, period, 0,
            &communicator);
    MPI_Cart_coords(communicator, rank, nDimension, coardinates);
    return communicator;
}

// this function calls other functions that I guess are not relevent to my problem
void shearSort(cube *SpecificCube, int my_rank, MPI_Comm Cube_Comm, int p,
        MPI_Datatype MPI_CUBE, int *coordinates) {
    int matrixSize = sqrt(p);
    int i;
    int IteratuionsLoops = ceil(log2(matrixSize) + 1);
    for (i = 0; i <= IteratuionsLoops; i++) { 
        OESort(SpecificCube, my_rank, 1, Cube_Comm, matrixSize, MPI_CUBE);
        OESort(SpecificCube, my_rank, 0, Cube_Comm, matrixSize, MPI_CUBE);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    int my_rank; /* rank of process */
    int p; /* number of processes */
    MPI_Datatype MPI_CUBE;
    MPI_Comm cubeComm;
    int i;
    int coordinates[2];
    cube *specificCube;
    cube **cArray;
    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv); // start up MPI
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &my_rank); // find out process rank
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &p); // find out number of processes

    if (my_rank == MASTER) {
        cArray = (cube**) malloc(LENGTH * sizeof(cube*));
        for (i = 0; i < LENGTH; i++) {
            cArray[i] = (cube*) malloc(sizeof(cube));
        }
        readFromFile(cArray, "cuboids.dat");
    }

    createNewCubeMPIType(&MPI_CUBE);
    cubeComm = createCommunicator(my_rank, p, coordinates);
    MPI_Scatter(cArray, 1, MPI_CUBE, &specificCube, 1, MPI_CUBE, MASTER,
            cubeComm);
    shearSort(specificCube, my_rank, cubeComm, p, MPI_CUBE, coordinates);
    MPI_Gather(&specificCube, 1, MPI_CUBE, cArray, 1, MPI_CUBE, MASTER,
            cubeComm);

    if (my_rank == MASTER) {
        writeCubesToFile(cArray,p);
        free_vars();
    }
    /* shut down MPI */
    MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

I tried to debug which line is the source of this message and 2 lines are suspected to cause the problem:

```
MPI_Scatter(cArray, 1, MPI_CUBE, &specificCube, 1, MPI_CUBE, MASTER,
         cubeComm);
shearSort(specificCube, my_rank, cubeComm, p, MPI_CUBE, coordinates);
```

The error message:

```
[ParallelCV2-15:26023] *** Process received signal ***
[ParallelCV2-15:26023] Signal: Segmentation fault (11)
[ParallelCV2-15:26023] Signal code: Address not mapped (1)
[ParallelCV2-15:26023] Failing at address: 0x2148250
[ParallelCV2-15:26026] *** Process received signal ***
[ParallelCV2-15:26026] Signal: Segmentation fault (11)
[ParallelCV2-15:26026] Signal code: Address not mapped (1)
[ParallelCV2-15:26026] Failing at address: 0x21499a0
[ParallelCV2-15:26021] *** Process received signal ***
[ParallelCV2-15:26021] Signal: Segmentation fault (11)
[ParallelCV2-15:26021] Signal code: Address not mapped (1)
[ParallelCV2-15:26021] Failing at address: 0x2145ce0
[ParallelCV2-15:26021] [ 0] /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0x11390)[0x7f157ee33390]
[ParallelCV2-15:26021] [ 1] guy[0x40149f]
[ParallelCV2-15:26021] [ 2] guy[0x40136b]
[ParallelCV2-15:26021] [ 3] guy[0x401420]
[ParallelCV2-15:26021] [ 4] guy[0x401817]
[ParallelCV2-15:26021] [ 5] [ParallelCV2-15:26026] [ 0] /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0x11390)[0x7fd5d8356390]
[ParallelCV2-15:26026] [ 1] guy[0x40149f]
[ParallelCV2-15:26026] [ 2] guy[0x40136b]
[ParallelCV2-15:26026] [ 3] guy[0x401420]
[ParallelCV2-15:26026] [ 4] guy[0x401817]
[ParallelCV2-15:26026] [ 5] /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf0)[0x7fd5d7f9b830]
[ParallelCV2-15:26026] [ 6] guy[0x400e09]
[ParallelCV2-15:26026] *** End of error message ***
[ParallelCV2-15:26032] *** Process received signal ***
[ParallelCV2-15:26032] Signal: Segmentation fault (11)
[ParallelCV2-15:26032] Signal code: Address not mapped (1)
[ParallelCV2-15:26032] Failing at address: (nil)
[ParallelCV2-15:26035] *** Process received signal ***
[ParallelCV2-15:26035] Signal: Segmentation fault (11)
[ParallelCV2-15:26035] Signal code: Address not mapped (1)
[ParallelCV2-15:26035] Failing at address: 0xa0
[ParallelCV2-15:26035] [ 0] /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0x11390)[0x7fe6adfd7390]
[ParallelCV2-15:26035] [ 1] guy[0x40149f]
[ParallelCV2-15:26035] [ 2] guy[0x40136b]
[ParallelCV2-15:26035] [ 3] guy[0x401420]
[ParallelCV2-15:26035] [ 4] guy[0x401817]
[ParallelCV2-15:26035] [ 5] /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf0)[0x7fe6adc1c830]
[ParallelCV2-15:26035] [ 6] guy[0x400e09]
[ParallelCV2-15:26035] *** End of error message ***
[ParallelCV2-15:26037] *** Process received signal ***
[ParallelCV2-15:26037] Signal: Segmentation fault (11)
[ParallelCV2-15:26037] Signal code: Address not mapped (1)
[ParallelCV2-15:26037] Failing at address: 0x75aa8c0
[ParallelCV2-15:26039] *** Process received signal ***
[ParallelCV2-15:26039] Signal: Segmentation fault (11)
[ParallelCV2-15:26039] Signal code: Address not mapped (1)
[ParallelCV2-15:26039] Failing at address: 0x18
[ParallelCV2-15:26039] [ 0] /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0x11390)[0x7f853bae8390]
[ParallelCV2-15:26039] [ 1] guy[0x40149f]
[ParallelCV2-15:26039] [ 2] guy[0x40136b]
[ParallelCV2-15:26039] [ 3] guy[0x401420]
[ParallelCV2-15:26039] [ 4] guy[0x401817]
[ParallelCV2-15:26039] [ 5] /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf0)[0x7f853b72d830]
[ParallelCV2-15:26039] [ 6] guy[0x400e09]
[ParallelCV2-15:26039] *** End of error message ***
[ParallelCV2-15:26038] *** Process received signal ***
[ParallelCV2-15:26038] Signal: Segmentation fault (11)
[ParallelCV2-15:26038] Signal code:  (128)
[ParallelCV2-15:26038] Failing at address: (nil)
[ParallelCV2-15:26038] [ 0] /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0x11390)[0x7f5eeb0ce390]
[ParallelCV2-15:26038] [ 1] guy[0x40149f]
[ParallelCV2-15:26038] [ 2] guy[0x40136b]
[ParallelCV2-15:26038] [ 3] guy[0x401420]
[ParallelCV2-15:26038] [ 4] guy[0x401817]
[ParallelCV2-15:26038] [ 5] /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf0)[0x7f5eead13830]
[ParallelCV2-15:26038] [ 6] guy[0x400e09]
[ParallelCV2-15:26038] *** End of error message ***
[ParallelCV2-15:26042] *** Process received signal ***
[ParallelCV2-15:26042] Signal: Segmentation fault (11)
[ParallelCV2-15:26042] Signal code: Address not mapped (1)
[ParallelCV2-15:26042] Failing at address: 0x7f30ac996920
[ParallelCV2-15:26042] [ 0] /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0x11390)[0x7f3ef3669390]
[ParallelCV2-15:26042] [ 1] guy[0x40149f]
[ParallelCV2-15:26042] [ 2] guy[0x40136b]
[ParallelCV2-15:26042] [ 3] guy[0x401420]
[ParallelCV2-15:26042] [ 4] guy[0x401817]
[ParallelCV2-15:26042] [ 5] /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf0)[0x7f3ef32ae830]
[ParallelCV2-15:26042] [ 6] guy[0x400e09]
[ParallelCV2-15:26042] *** End of error message ***
[ParallelCV2-15:26045] *** Process received signal ***
[ParallelCV2-15:26045] Signal: Segmentation fault (11)
[ParallelCV2-15:26045] Signal code:  (128)
[ParallelCV2-15:26045] Failing at address: (nil)
[ParallelCV2-15:26045] [ 0] /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0x11390)[0x7f8d78b65390]
[ParallelCV2-15:26045] [ 1] guy[0x40149f]
[ParallelCV2-15:26045] [ 2] guy[0x40136b]
[ParallelCV2-15:26045] [ 3] guy[0x401420]
[ParallelCV2-15:26045] [ 4] guy[0x401817]
[ParallelCV2-15:26045] [ 5] /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf0)[0x7f8d787aa830]
[ParallelCV2-15:26045] [ 6] guy[0x400e09]
[ParallelCV2-15:26045] *** End of error message ***
[ParallelCV2-15:26029] *** Process received signal ***
[ParallelCV2-15:26029] Signal: Segmentation fault (11)
[ParallelCV2-15:26029] Signal code: Address not mapped (1)
[ParallelCV2-15:26029] Failing at address: 0x2149a60
[ParallelCV2-15:26032] [ 0] /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0x11390)[0x7f7abfde6390]
[ParallelCV2-15:26032] [ 1] guy[0x40149f]
[ParallelCV2-15:26032] [ 2] guy[0x40136b]
[ParallelCV2-15:26032] [ 3] guy[0x401420]
[ParallelCV2-15:26032] [ 4] guy[0x401817]
[ParallelCV2-15:26032] [ 5] /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf0)[0x7f7abfa2b830]
[ParallelCV2-15:26032] [ 6] guy[0x400e09]
[ParallelCV2-15:26032] *** End of error message ***
[ParallelCV2-15:26037] [ 0] /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0x11390)[0x7f6698e42390]
[ParallelCV2-15:26037] [ 1] guy[0x40149f]
[ParallelCV2-15:26037] [ 2] guy[0x40136b]
[ParallelCV2-15:26037] [ 3] guy[0x401420]
[ParallelCV2-15:26037] [ 4] guy[0x401817]
[ParallelCV2-15:26037] [ 5] /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf0)[0x7f6698a87830]
[ParallelCV2-15:26037] [ 6] guy[0x400e09]
[ParallelCV2-15:26037] *** End of error message ***
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf0)[0x7f157ea78830]
[ParallelCV2-15:26021] [ 6] guy[0x400e09]
[ParallelCV2-15:26021] *** End of error message ***
[ParallelCV2-15:26023] [ 0] /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0x11390)[0x7f2be2338390]
[ParallelCV2-15:26023] [ 1] guy[0x40149f]
[ParallelCV2-15:26023] [ 2] [ParallelCV2-15:26040] *** Process received signal ***
[ParallelCV2-15:26040] Signal: Segmentation fault (11)
[ParallelCV2-15:26040] Signal code: Address not mapped (1)
[ParallelCV2-15:26040] Failing at address: (nil)
[ParallelCV2-15:26040] [ 0] /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0x11390)[0x7fd0a36fa390]
[ParallelCV2-15:26040] [ 1] guy[0x40149f]
[ParallelCV2-15:26040] [ 2] guy[0x40136b]
guy[0x40136b]
[ParallelCV2-15:26023] [ 3] guy[0x401420]
[ParallelCV2-15:26023] [ 4] guy[0x401817]
[ParallelCV2-15:26023] [ 5] /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf0)[0x7f2be1f7d830]
[ParallelCV2-15:26023] [ 6] guy[0x400e09]
[ParallelCV2-15:26023] *** End of error message ***
[ParallelCV2-15:26029] [ 0] /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0x11390)[0x7efcd513b390]
[ParallelCV2-15:26029] [ 1] guy[0x40149f]
[ParallelCV2-15:26029] [ 2] guy[0x40136b]
[ParallelCV2-15:26029] [ 3] guy[0x401420]
[ParallelCV2-15:26029] [ 4] guy[0x401817]
[ParallelCV2-15:26029] [ 5] /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf0)[0x7efcd4d80830]
[ParallelCV2-15:26029] [ 6] guy[0x400e09]
[ParallelCV2-15:26029] *** End of error message ***
[ParallelCV2-15:26040] [ 3] guy[0x401420]
[ParallelCV2-15:26040] [ 4] guy[0x401817]
[ParallelCV2-15:26040] [ 5] /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf0)[0x7fd0a333f830]
[ParallelCV2-15:26040] [ 6] guy[0x400e09]
[ParallelCV2-15:26040] *** End of error message ***
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
mpiexec noticed that process rank 5 with PID 26026 on node ParallelCV2-15 exited on signal 11 (Segmentation fault).
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Thank you for your time.

Comment: If you compile your code with debug information (`-g`), you may even get function names and line numbers in the stack trace.

Comment: `cArray` is a jagged array and this is something you should avoid with MPI. Instead, make it a pointer so your `cube` are contiguous in memory. Generally speaking, you need to `MPI_Type_create_resized()` your datatype since the compiler might add some padding, and as a matter of style, you might want to use the `offsetof()` macro to compute the displacements.